# issue with disag_model() function from disaggregation R package

Tags: r

I was trying to use the disaggregation package to evaluate if it could be used on the dataset I have. My original data are disaggregated, so I've aggregated them to use the disag_model function from disaggregation package and compare "fitted values" with actual values. 
However when I run the function the R session aborts.
I tried to execute the disag_model function step by step and I saw that the problem is due to the use of nlminb() to optimize the a posteriori density function, but I cannot understand why it's happening and how to solve it.
Thanks for your help.

You can find the data I used at this link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/au7l0e11trzfo19/AACpfRSUpd4gRCveUsh5JX6Ea?dl=0
Please download the folder to run the code.
This is the code I used:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
library(disaggregation)
library(sp)

path<- "yourPath/Data"

load(file.path(path, "myRS"))
load(file.path(path, "RAST"))


Data <- read.csv(file = paste(path, "/sim_data.csv", sep = ""))
Data$HasRes <- ifelse(Data$PN50 > runif(nrow(Data)), 1, 0)
for (i in 1:nlayers(myRS)) {
  myRS@layers[[i]]@file@name<-file.path(path, "predStackl10")
}
DFCov <-
  as.data.frame(raster::extract(myRS, Data[c("XCoord", "YCoord")]))
Data <- cbind(Data, DFCov)

# Remove NA
NAs <- which(is.na(rowSums(Data[names(myRS)])))
Data <- Data[-NAs, ]
Data$ISO3 <- as.factor(Data$ISO3)

world_shape <-
  shapefile(file.path(path, "World.shp"))
lmic_shape <-
  world_shape[(world_shape@data$ISO3 %in% levels(Data$ISO3)),]
plot(lmic_shape)


# I would like to convert Data in a SpatialPointsDataFrame object
PN50 <- Data
coordinates(PN50) <- c("XCoord", "YCoord")
is.projected(PN50) # see if a projection is defined
proj4string(PN50) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")



# compute the mean P50 within each state
PN50_mean <- aggregate(x = PN50,
                       by = list(Data$ISO3),
                       FUN = mean)
# compute the centroid of the observations coordinates for each state
PN50_centroid <-
  Data %>% group_by(ISO3) %>% summarise(meanX = mean(XCoord), meanY = mean(YCoord))

# assign to each mean the centroid coordinates
PN50_agg <-
  as.data.frame(
    cbind(
      PN50_mean = PN50_mean@data$PN50,
      XCoord = PN50_centroid$meanX,
      YCoord = PN50_centroid$meanY
    )
  )
PN50_agg$XCoord <- as.numeric(PN50_agg$XCoord)
PN50_agg$YCoord <- as.numeric(PN50_agg$YCoord)
PN50_agg$ISO3 <- as.character(PN50_centroid$ISO3)
samsiz <-
  Data %>% group_by(ISO3) %>% summarise(sz = sum(SampleSize))
PN50_agg$sample_size <- as.numeric(samsiz$sz)
PN50_agg$case <- round(PN50_agg$PN50_mean * PN50_agg$sample_size)

# I would like having data in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame format to use the disaggrgation package
library(sp)
coordinates(PN50_agg) <- c("XCoord", "YCoord")
proj4string(PN50_agg) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
PN50_polyg <- lmic_shape
PN50_polyg@data <-
   full_join(PN50_polyg@data, PN50_agg@data, by = "ISO3")


# covariates raster 

covariate_stack <-
  getCovariateRasters(path, shape = raster(x = paste0(path, '/multi.tif')))
names(covariate_stack)
covariate_stack2 <- dropLayer(covariate_stack, nlayers(covariate_stack))
names(covariate_stack2)
plot(covariate_stack2)
covariate_stack2 <- raster::stack(covariate_stack2)
covariate_stack2<-brick(covariate_stack2)

# population raster

extracted <- raster::extract(raster(x = paste0(path, '/multi.tif')), PN50_polyg)
n_cells <- sapply(extracted, length)
PN50_polyg@data$pop_per_cell <- PN50_polyg@data$sample_size / n_cells

population_raster <-
  rasterize(PN50_polyg, covariate_stack2, field = 'pop_per_cell')

# prepare data for disag_model()

dis_data <- prepare_data(
  polygon_shapefile = PN50_polyg,
  covariate_rasters = covariate_stack2,
  aggregation_raster = population_raster,
  mesh.args = list(
    max.edge = c(5, 40),
    cut = 0.0005,
    offset = 1
  ),
  id_var = "ISO3",
  response_var = "case",
  sample_size_var = "sample_size",
  na.action = TRUE,
  ncores = 8
)


# Rho and p(Rho<Rho_min)
dist <- pointDistance(PN50_agg@coords, lonlat = F, allpairs = T)
rownames(dist) <- PN50_agg$ISO3
colnames(dist) <- PN50_agg$ISO3

flattenDist <- function(dist) {
  up <- upper.tri(dist)
  flat <- data_frame(row = rownames(dist)[row(dist)[up]],
                     column = rownames(dist)[col(dist)[up]],
                     dist = dist[up])
  return(flat)
}
pair_dist <- flattenDist(dist)
d <- pair_dist$dist
k <- 0.036
CorMatern <- k * d * besselK(k * d, 1)
limits <- sp::bbox(PN50_polyg)
hypontenuse <-
  sqrt((limits[1, 2] - limits[1, 1]) ^ 2 + (limits[2, 2] - limits[2, 1]) ^
         2)
prior_rho <- hypontenuse / 3
p_rho <- sum(d[CorMatern <= 0.1] < prior_rho) / length(d[CorMatern <= 0.1])

# sigma and p(sigma>sigma_max)
sigma_boost <- function(data, i) {
  sd(data[i] / mean(data[i]))
}
sigma <-
  boot(data = dis_data$polygon_data$response,
       statistic = sigma_boost,
       10000)

prior_sigma <- sigma$t0
p_sigma <- sum(sigma$t >= sigma$t0) / length(sigma$t)

default_priors <-
  list(
    priormean_intercept = 0,
    priorsd_intercept = 4,
    priormean_slope = 0,
    priorsd_slope = 2,
    prior_rho_min = prior_rho,
    prior_rho_prob = p_rho,
    prior_sigma_max = prior_sigma,
    prior_sigma_prob = p_sigma,
    prior_iideffect_sd_max = 0.1,
    prior_iideffect_sd_prob = 0.01
  )

fitted_model <- disag_model(
  data = dis_data,
  iterations = 1000,
  family = "binomial",
  link = "logit",
  # priors = default_priors,
  field = TRUE,
  iid = TRUE,
  silent = TRUE
)
```

Comment: I have tried using the fit_model function (instead of disag_model) from the previous version of the disaggregation package. The R session still aborts due to the same problem with nlminb

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the query. The dropbox link just goes to "/Data" could you please correct the link so we can have a look? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the correct link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/au7l0e11trzfo19/AACpfRSUpd4gRCveUsh5JX6Ea?dl=0

Comment: Hi again. Anita is handling most of this but doesn't have reputation to comment, so I'm acting as a go between! Please bare with us if we're a little slow. We can't seem to load those rasters. myRS just contains the metadata and points to a file /Users/gbrunelli/Dropbox/resbank/data/predStackl10.grd. Happy to carry on trying to help if we can get the files!

Comment: sorry again, I add that file to the dropbox folder. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've changed the code a little to change the layers source of myRS so that it takes the file from the "Data" folder

Comment: Hi. We still can't use the data in the dropbox folder as they are still metadata without the actual raster data. You can tell partially because the files are very small.

Two things you could try
Firstly, can I double check that p_rho is a probability? Actually it looks like it is.

Secondly, perhaps you could save `dis_data` as an RData or rds file and put that in the dropbox. We should be able to run (with different priors) using that.

Comment: I've saved dis_data as RData in the dropbox. p_rho it's a probability. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to run the disag_model function using your dis_data object. There were no errors or crashes. I ran the following lines.

```
fitted_model <- disag_model(
  data = dis_data,
  iterations = 1000,
  family = "binomial",
  link = "logit",
  field = TRUE,
  iid = TRUE,
  silent = TRUE
)
```

I am running on a Windows machine with 64GB RAM and 8 cores. It took over an hour and used all of my RAM for a while and up to 50% of my CPU, which is not surprising as you are fitting 5.5M pixels over the whole world. Therefore, I suspect it is related to your computer running out of resources. I suggest you try a smaller example to test it out first. Try fewer polygons and fewer pixels in each polygon.

Comment: Hi @G0904B. If this did answer your question you might consider clicking the tick to make Anita's answer the accepted answer. Thanks again for getting in touch!